# How to set up a proper development environment

Tags: azure-pipelines

We have a classic setup in Azure Dev Ops with code repos and pipelines. We build some Visual Studio Projects, and deploy it to function apps and web apps.

I have been working very little with it and find it pretty cumbersome to debug and develop pipelines. How do you guys work with it? Is it possible to do it with powershell scripts locally, for better debug and development, and then upload it following for running in production? Or what is the prefered approach?

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to check the answer below to enable debug logs? If you have specific query to use pipeline, please share more details in the original post to help understand your concern. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the document for your reference to enable and view pipeline debug logs.

[Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops)

You can either check `Enable system diagnostics option` before running your pipeline manually or set the variable `system.debug` as `true` to enable debug logs.

[image]

If you come across some errors during the pipeline build, you may also test locally with the command(s) in blue, which is the actual command(s) that each pipeline task executes.
[image]